# delete same data in one table with syntax error(mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

There are same url in my table. Each row can be identified by id. 
I want to delete same data in `url` fields. I am using mysql. 
I am trying `select` one(identified by the maximum id) of them as a new tempary table as `t2`, and then compare `url` between the original table and the tempary table in my `where` clause. There is syntax error in my statements, but I am not sure where it is. can u help me? thx guys.

The statements as follow:

```
delete from t1, 
(select url, max(id) as id
        from tjob_webpage as t1 
        group by url
) as t2 
where t1.url = t2.url 
      t1.id < t2.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
delete t1
from t1 INNER JOIN
(select url, max(id)  maxID
        from tjob_webpage
        group by url
) as t2 
where t1.url = t2.url 
      t1.id < t2.maxID;
```

Comment: thx John Woo, It works as `delete tjob_webpage from tjob_webpage INNER JOIN (select url, max(id) maxID from tjob_webpage group by url ) t2 where tjob_webpage.url = t2.url  and tjob_webpage.id < t2.maxID;`